# What variables are in the Drupal $primary_nav variable

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How would I pull an array of all the labels and links for every menu item in the $primary_nav variable?

Comment: I was to pull the primary nav variable, then I want to loop through all the elements in that variable. From those elements, I want to pull a list of every navigation label along with every link associated with it.

Comment: You described what you want to do. What have you tried so far ? What is the issue here, is it about Drupal theme variables, is it about how to loop through array/objects in PHP ??

Comment: You will always have a better intuition of how to achieve what you want by debugging your variables to understand how it is structured (eg. is it a nested array of objects or a flat integer list ?) before eventually using it, looping through elements and grabbing what you need. Nobody can do this for you, but you can eventually post debug outputs, error logs or code sample, so you can receive more dedicated help, but remember to stay generic so that other users can benefit your post and its answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use php's [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). Or use a dedicated module like [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) : it provides helpers which pretty print variables including arrays and objects. It also provides a clear cache button, can generate random nodes, etc.

I think devel's `dprint_r()` and `dpm()` are the most used functions and the most useful I guess for Drupal developers when it comes to print and debug variables.

In your case, `$primary_nav` is a ***processed*** variable : it is first prepared by functions from the registered theme, then it can be altered in ***process*** or ***preprocess*** **hooks** provided by themes and/or modules.

Knowing that, you can either print it right from the template you are working on, like *page.tpl.php* :

```
<?php if (!empty($primary_nav)): ?>
  <!--<?php print render($primary_nav); ?>-->
  <?php dpm($primary_nav); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

.. or debug it "earlier" in a *process* or *preprocess* function like :

```
function some_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables['primary_nav']);
}
```

Also, if you don't know what is going on or what variables are available in a template, combining php's [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) with a pretty print function can be vey helpful : `dpm(get_defined_vars());`